# How do I duplicate jackal model tag in Halo PC campaign without exception errors?(Not Custom Edition)

Tags: halo-combat-evolved

I'm trying to replace the single green jackal shield in the campaign with yellow and blue shields like it was in the original xbox version. And the way I tried to do that was by duplicating the characters\jackal\jackal model tag.
What I did was open and expand the map in question in eschaton 0.8.1, and open (not expand), a second map to extract the tag from. So I extract the jackal model tag from the opened map, then import it into the expanded map with "do not import duplicates" unchecked.

I then rebuilt the map with the duplicate tag, which is assigned a plus sign to differentiate it from the original, including its dependencies.
Then I reopened the map in eschaton and clicked on the jackal major biped tag and swapped its model to the duplicated one. I then opened up halo map tools v3.5 and injected a blue shield texture to the original bitmap, and a yellow texture to the duplicate with the plus sign.

Next I tested it out by playing the campaign, which works perfectly with one glaring problem, it crashes during the cutscenes and gives me an exception error. Every level I do this to crashes during the cutscenes. I even expanded the base map that I took the tag from and renamed the tag and its dependencies so there wouldn't be duplicates, but the game still crashes during cutscenes.

Is my method just flawed? Is there another way to do this? Or is this not possible in vanilla Halo PC without exceptions?

Again this is Halo PC, not Custom Edition, and I'm trying to have two colors of jackal shield, yellow and blue, like in the xbox version of Halo CE.

Update: it seems I answered my own problem; I used an earlier version of eschaton(0.7.2) to rebuild the map, and it didn't crash!
If you want to successfully open and expand/rebuild campaign maps, use eschaton 0.7.2 or maybe 0.8.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? change the color of the Jackal shields?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to have two different colors of shields: blue for jackal minors and yellow for majors.